# Do common DAC USB interfaces fare well with DC in line inputs?

Tags: dac

Do common pro DAC USB interfaces, I mean signal going from analog to digital input (TRS/XLR-input), in general, fare well, can they handle and take dc in line/xlr/instrument inputs?
Specifically in general those DACs with 2k-10k input impedance, those digital once I'm askin without transformers and just with converters, without getting damaged?

General question, as I searched the web and found nothing specific or general about it.

I do have a DAC from a certain company but I don't want to shill any company.

I'm new to audio experiments too, and don't want to find out by trying as it's expensive. Thanks!

PS: If yes, they do handle dc well in their inputs in general, then my next question would be. Do the same rated max dBu input levels apply here as for ac in the specs (in general)?

Comment: Can you clarify how this is related to sound design? DC is not audio rate information so it’s not clear how this involves sound.

Comment: I guess you med ADC (Analog to Digital Converter), not DAC (Digital to Analog Converter).

Comment: The problem with the question is that it depends on the actual ADC as well as the actual DC on the signal inputs. As one example, XLR inputs that can provide 48V Phantom power have circuits that can take at leaste 48V DC without problems. This might or might not be true for TRS inputs on same interface. Regardless, sound DAC units filter out the DC, say below 20 Hz (or slightly lower).